# Firmware over the air algorithm

Tags: c, firmware

I'm doing firmware over the air update, but I don't know how long will it take to download the firmware and upgrade the device. So what I have tried is to go into infinite loop `while(1)` and check if the firmware is finished upgrading. That fcked up the devices on the street... The other option is to do timeout but for how long? It's unpredictable.
The question is, how to ensure realiability and do it correctly?

Here is what I have tried:

```
signed char wait_commands(vu32 timeout, char*command, const char *result_command, int valueToCheck)
{
    char *result = NULL;
        
    timer_1sec = 0;

        while(timer_1sec < timeout)
        {
            if( GSMGetString(tempdata, 5) == OK)
            {
            result = strstr(tempdata, command);
            if ( result != NULL)
            {
                int value;
                if ( result_command != NULL)
                {
                    if( valueToCheck != -1)
                    {
                        if (sscanf(result, result_command, &value) > 0)
                        {
                            
                            if (value != valueToCheck)
                            {
                                return FEHLER; 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return OK;
                            }
                        }
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    return OK;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FEHLER;
}

u8 isUpdated(void)
{
        
    char *currentFirmwareVersion = "BG96MAR02A07M1G_01.019.01.019";

    while (GSMCommand("+QGMR", tempdata, 20) != AT_OK)
        ;
    
    if (strncmp(tempdata, currentFirmwareVersion, strlen(currentFirmwareVersion))==0)
    {
        isBG96Updated = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        isBG96Updated = 0;
        
    }
    
    return isBG96Updated;
}

signed char updateBG96FirmwareVersion(vu32 timeout)
{
    char *url = "\"http://10.10.169.1/dfota/upgrade.bin\"";
    char command[150] = {0};
    signed char res = FEHLER;
    
    if(isUpdated())
        return OK;
    
    sprintf(command, "AT+QFOTADL=%s", url);
    PutStringUART(UART_GSM, command);
    PutCharUART(UART_GSM, '\r');
    res = wait_commands(timeout, "\"FOTA\",\"HTTPSTART\"", NULL, -1);
    res = wait_commands(timeout, "\"FOTA\",\"END\"",  "\"FOTA\",\"END\",%d", 0);
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Can you send the first few bytes (4??) with the amount of bytes for the whole thing?

Comment: @pmg there is no such mechanism.. The BG96 Chip update is not predictable in a way of its steps.. but at the end it goes to the string ```END```, that's why I'm checking that... and trying to parse it for the result..

Comment: @pmg  how would I send the first 4 bytes ? I can only issue AT Commands to the device. I didn't get it

Comment: I don't know how "FOTA" works, what protocols are defined for it. But if you control the server and the clients you can use whatever you want. Again: I don't know FOTA; take what I say with a (large) pinch of salt.

Comment: @pmg You're right, in general, about the fact that if you control both the server and the client, then you can implement firmware upgrades however you want (I once implemented upgrades over-the-air via NFC for a tiny NFC card that ran custom software, it was fun). But alas, it's not possible for all devices to have this kind of control over firmware upgrades. And I suspect that OP's chip is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with the Quectel BG96 chip, specifically, but it appears to support DFOTA, and there is also an official guide that you can view/download [here](https://github.com/top-electronics/ERF3000-v2/blob/master/Docs/AT%20Manuals/Quectel_BG96_DFOTA_User_Guide_V1.1.pdf).

This guide contains the AT commands necessary to upgrade the firmware over-the-air. Plus, I think it may clarify your doubts about the upgrade procedure.

Comment: I did the same as the documentation says, as you see from my code. But I don't know the way to correctly do it in terms of the algorithm using timeout or infinite loop

Comment: @andreahmed When you send the AT command to the chip, it will respond with the percent of the current progress. For instance, it will respond `+QIND: "FOTA","UPDATING",50%` to let you know that upgrade is 50% complete. When it's finished, it will return `+QIND: "FOTA","END",0` in case of success. So you have to wait and parse the responses until you get `+QIND: "FOTA","END",0` (or `ERROR`, in case of errors).

Comment: @andreahmed How to implement it heavily depends on what is the client you use to send the command. Are you using Linux? Windows? What is the library you're using to send commands to the chip?

Comment: I'm using normal stm32f firmware for writing UART AT Commands. Would you show please a pseudo code ? You can find my code snippet if you need more information on how I did it... the way it is now

Comment: ```So you have to wait and parse the responses until you get``` that's my issue actually... would you show a pseudo code of it please :)

Comment: @andreahmed I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with UART on STM32F. I don't know which library you use for UART on STM32F, but the general pseudocode is `while (1) { char resp[100]; get_line(resp, 100); if (strcmp(resp, "+QIND: \"FOTA\",\"END\",0") == 0 || strcmp(resp, "ERROR") == 0) { break; } } /* update finished */`. You need a `get_line()` function that receives bytes from the UART until `"\r\n"` is received (in case BG96 uses `"\r\n"` as newline).